# Installation Option for ASP .NET Web Service Application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, installation

I am trying to create an ASP .NET Web Service Application using Visual Studio 2005 (Version 8.0.50727.42). Unfortunately, I do not get any options for creating such a project. I am guessing it has to do with Visual Studio installation options.

I am only enabling the components Visual C#, Visual Web Developer and SQL server 2005. I am hoping this would be enough. Is this ok, or should I go for default installation options.

Is this even a setup issue, or does the problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: A fresh installation now enables me to create ASP .NET Web Service, but it's now under Visual C++ and not Visual C#. How can I move it under Visual C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install Visual Studio Service Pack 1. This did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

A web service application is just a web application with .asmx "services" instead of .aspx "pages".

Once you've got a web application the option to add a service should exist in about the same place as to add a "form" or a page.

Methods need to be annotated appropriately but there's not a lot more to it than that.

Of course... ideally you'd want to be creating WCF services rather than web services but equally in an ideal world you'd be using at least VS2008 and .NET 3.5SP1.

Comment: Thanks for all that. I have learned Web Services using VS2008, but currently I am working in a team thats working with VS2005. So, there isn't much under my control.